# Solve this equation $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}(\frac{x}{n})^k=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Solve this equation $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}(\frac{x}{n})^k=0$$

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail?

Answer (score 3):

Reversing the summation order, the sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(k+1) x^k $$

which converges for $x \in (-1,1)$ and is equal to

$$-\gamma-\psi(1-x)$$

A plot of this function over $x \in (-1,1)$ reveals a zero only at $x=0$.

Comment: (+1) We have to be careful in switching the order of summation since this is not always legit, but apart from that your answer is perfectly fine. We can also notice that $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\zeta(k+1)x^k$$ is an increasing function over $(-1,1)$ by computing its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}(\frac{x}{n})^k=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{n}} - 1 \right) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n} \frac{x}{n-x} =
x \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{n-x} \right)$$
Clearly, LHS cannot be $0$ for $x > 0$, while RHS cannot be $0$ for $x<0$. So the only solution is $x=0$.

Comment: Very nice elementary argument. Additional remark: Since for $n = 1$ the inner sum converges only for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, the sum right hand side is strictly positive for all legitimate $x$ (and if we allow complex $x$, the real part of the sum is $> 0$ for all legitimate $x$), so we could argue with the RHS only. (I'm not saying that would be better, it's always good to use the obvious things immediately.)

Answer (score -1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}(\frac{x}{n})^k=0 $$

Which implies

$\frac{1}{n} (\frac{x}{n})^k = 0$

Therefore $x^k = 0$

So $x=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: If $x<0$, not every the term of the double series is $\neq 0$, hence it might be a negative solution, even if this is not the case.

Comment: sorry to burst your bubble but the series diverges if $x<0$, for example, $x=-10$.

Check the other post mate.

Comment: why the series should be divergent for $x=-1/2$?

Comment: because then $x<0$, which as I said before, means the series diverges

Comment: simply false. The double series for $x=-1/2$ equals $-2+\log 4$.

Comment: Yes but the series diverges to $-2+log4$, I don't know what is so hard to understand about this.

Comment: what is your definition of "divergent series"? Usually, we say that a series that converges to a negative real number is "convergent".